# I wanted to upload a profile for my site but there's an error in the #FileUpload2 line

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I try to upload a profile for my site I get an exception in this line

`FileUpload2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/moreinfo/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload2.FileName));`

Code:

```cs
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DatabaseCollege"].ConnectionString);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/logos/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName));
    String link = "logos/" + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);

    FileUpload2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/moreinfo/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload2.FileName));
    String filename = "moreinfo/" + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload2.FileName);
    // Label1.Text = Session["UserName"].ToString();
    String query = "INSERT INTO Notice VALUES('" + link + "','" + filename + "','" + txtrequirements.Text + "','" + txtlocation.Text + "','" + txtdate.Text + "','" + txtCompany.Text + "','" + txtwebsite.Text + "','" + Session["Username"] + "')";
    // String query = "Insert into Notice values('" + link + "','" + Session["UserName"] + "','" + txtCompany.Text + "','" + txtwebsite.Text + "','" + txtrequirements.Text + "','" + txtlocation.Text + "','" + txtdate.Text + "')";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    con.Open(); ;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Popup", "successalert();", true);
    txtrequirements.Text = "";
    txtlocation.Text = "";
    txtdate.Text = "";
    txtCompany.Text = "";
    txtwebsite.Text="";
}
```

Exception:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Just as I thought, the Exception is because the path you are using cannot be found. Debug `Server.MapPath("~/moreinfo/")` and see what you are getting.